# Loop output in R Dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new to R and looking to get `for` loop output in each iteration in one dataframe. Below is the code, where I am trying to get data in `Results` dataframe

```
for (i in 1:nrow(base_data)) {
LCS1 <- expand.grid(STREET=base_data$STREET[1:nrow(base_data)],REF_STREET=base_data$STREET[i])
LCS$LCS_stringdist=stringdist(LCS$STREET,LCS$Name1,method="lcs")
Results <- head(LCS[order(LCS$LCS_stringdist),],20) 
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean *get data in Results dataframe*? What is the error or undesired results? What is current data and desired result?

Comment: `head(..., 20)` will return the top 20 rows of the LCS data frame. So you want to add 20 rows to `Results` at each iteration through the loop?

Comment: @Gregor Yes, I want to add top 20 observation from each iteration to the final result

Comment: @Parfait I have data like below 
`    NAME
      ----
    Balachandra
    Sunita
    Kali
   Jagmeet`

The desired result should be like 
`    NAME1       NAME2             LCS
     ---------------------------------------
     Balachandra Balachandra     0
     Balachandra Sunita               6
     Balachandra Kali                   14
     Balachandra Jagmeet            4
     Sunita      Balachandra          6
     Sunita      Sunita                    0
     Sunita      Kali                         3
     Sunita      Jagmeet                 4`

Comment: Please edit your post with such information into clear tabular format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to assign to items of a list and then bind into a data frame at the end.

```
results_list = list()

for (i in 1:nrow(base_data)) {
  LCS1 <- expand.grid(STREET=base_data$STREET[1:nrow(base_data)],REF_STREET=base_data$STREET[i])
  LCS$LCS_stringdist=stringdist(LCS$STREET,LCS$Name1,method="lcs")
  results_list[[i]] <- head(LCS[order(LCS$LCS_stringdist),],20) 
}

Results = do.call(rbind, results_list)

## faster options in other packages
Results = dplyr::bind_rows(results_list)
Results = data.table::rbindlist(results_list)
```